# Wrap XElement with another XElement

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have a collections of XElements that I get like `doc.Root.Element("Doc").Elements("PersonalData")`.

Collection looks like that:

```
<PersonalData att1="0" att2="21" att3="2017">
        <element1>
          <data name="test test test" />
        </element1>
        <element2>
          <element3 att1="66725.67" att2="51769.82" >
            <data att1="03" att2="HP"/>
            <data att1="03" att2="HP"/>
            <data att1="03" att2="HP"/>
          </element3>
        </element2>
</PersonalData >
      <PersonalData att1="0" att2="21" att3="2017">
        <element1>
          <data name="test test test" />
        </element1>
        <element2>
          <element3 att1="66725.67" att2="51769.82" >
            <data att1="03" att2="HP"/>
            <data att1="03" att2="HP"/>
            <data att1="03" att2="HP"/>
          </element3>
        </element2>
</PersonalData >
```

I'd like to surround each element in collection with `<row>` element.

I've tried to do it like this:

```
foreach (var item in doc.Root.Element("Doc").Elements("PersonalData"))
            {
               item.AddBeforeSelf("<row>");
               item.AddAfterSelf("</row>");
            }
```

but except `"<"` I get `&lt &gt`.
Can I fix it somehow or can I do something like:

```
item.ReplaceWith(new XElement("row").Add(item));
```

How can I do it properly?

At the end it should look like:

```
<row>
<PersonalData att1="0" att2="21" att3="2017">
            <element1>
              <data name="test test test" />
            </element1>
            <element2>
              <element3 att1="66725.67" att2="51769.82" >
                <data att1="03" att2="HP"/>
                <data att1="03" att2="HP"/>
                <data att1="03" att2="HP"/>
              </element3>
            </element2>
    </PersonalData >
</row>
<row>
<PersonalData att1="0" att2="21" att3="2017">
            <element1>
              <data name="test test test" />
            </element1>
            <element2>
              <element3 att1="66725.67" att2="51769.82" >
                <data att1="03" att2="HP"/>
                <data att1="03" att2="HP"/>
                <data att1="03" att2="HP"/>
              </element3>
            </element2>
    </PersonalData >
</row>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you do it. You should never manipulate XML directly when using `System.Linq.Xml`.

Algorithm from the top of my head:

- Create a List elementsToDelete
- In your loop, add every item to this list, and add a new XElement(item) to item's parent element
- After the loop, do a new loop on elementsToDelete and remove all elements it contains from your items' parent element

That should be this in code:

```
var elementsToDelete = new List<XElement>();
var parentElement = doc.Root.Element("Doc");
foreach (var item in parentElement.Elements("PersonalData"))
{
    elementsToDelete.Add(item);
}

foreach (var element in elementsToDelete)
{
    element.Remove();
    parentElement.Add(new XElement("row", element));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use `ReplaceWith()`, you just need to collect the elements to be replaced beforehand since you cannot enumerate over a document's elements while you're actively modifying it. Just throwing them into a list is usually enough.

```
foreach (var pd in doc.Descendants("PersonalData").ToList())
    pd.ReplaceWith(new XElement("row", pd));
```